# Is it fine and normal to rely on HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory() as a constant?

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, truststore

If we look at [the source code of the Jersey](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/internal/HttpUrlConnector.java#L302-L304)'s `HttpUrlConnector`, we will find there such a construction:

```
if (HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory() == suc.getSSLSocketFactory()) {
       // indicates that the custom socket factory was not set
       suc.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory.get());
}
```

So basically what they do here is a sort of a lazy `SSLSocketFactory` initialization.

However, nobody guarantees that `HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory()` remains a constant. Furthermore, one can just freely invoke `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());` and break all the logic. Obviously if the condition in `if ()` is `false`, then the client will not be configured with a proper truststore with all consequences.

I have created a test which leverages this instability and always fails with `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed` exception: https://github.com/Andremoniy/jersey-bug-4332

I have also submitted a bug to jersey project: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4332 with [a proposal of the fix](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/pull/4335). However there is no reaction for already 2 weeks.

For me it sounds like a severe issue (we experience this problem in our projects based on jersey library very often). So I am surprised of the Jersey's team silence. Until only one possibility: they do not consider it as a bug and we probably do something wrong and the construction they used is just fine.

This is essentially my question: am I exaggerating the problem and there is possibly no bug at all?

P.S. Of course in our projects nothing directly invokes `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());` -- I used this technique to forcibly simulate instability. In reality a race condition happens which initializes the socket factory twice.